# Window/Door Sensors and Sensors for Security System

Tags: sensors

My goal is to possibly create my own security system (as opposed to paying for a company). My service will monitor a set of sensors that are installed on windows and doors, record events into an SQL server, and alert me by text message if needed.

My two questions are as following... where I can I get a set of sensors to put on my doors/windows that I can someway hook up to my computer. Secondly, how can I get this to work with C# (if possible)? The rest is easy but I don't know of any way to get started.

I have no background in hardware development and am strictly software based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reply of 1st Question**

Its depends on location  but i get your location from your profile and find this site maybe this one helps you 
[Door Sensors Omaha NE](http://local.homesecurityandalarms.com/Door_Sensors_Omaha_NE-p1712659-Omaha_NE.html)

**Reply of 2nd Question**

These types of things comes with its drivers and other things which help you in making this type of system and yes you can make this in C# all you have to do is just contact the above link directly via phone call and ask him which things he gives you to make a software for this and also ask him can he email you these things i mean the ocx or something else so that you can try to make this software and after receiving this ocx or something else when you face any problem try to search on google if you dont found any useful solution than ask here